# node.js convert binary string to number

Tags: javascript, node.js

Writing a node.js application, it receives from a socket a binary string of 4 bytes "\x00\x00\x00\x13", I need to convert it to integer (19 which is 0x13 in our case) using big endian order.

In other scripting languages, like perl, we can do unpack.
    unpack("N", )

In node.js, not sure how do do it.

Comment: `new Buffer(binaryString, "binary").toString('uft8')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Buffer('\x00\x00\x00\x13', 'binary').readInt32BE(0)
```

Comment: Please describe your answer. So codingFun can easily understand your answer and implement it.

Comment: @V.J. , the method name can be easily found using search, so it's very likely that the explanation won't be required. If it will, I'll be happy to answer him on request.

Comment: @alex it works for him. But in future some one looking for the same solution and he is new in this technology then your answer is not helpful to him. You are right at your point.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Wish I can upvote it (don't have enough reputation).

Answer (score 0):

npm is your friend here. The module **anybase** looks like it might be up to the task. Here's a link for more info: https://www.npmjs.org/package/anybase

Future tip: 
you can search npm from the commandline and probably find a module for most common things.
The syntax is like this:

```
npm search string1 string2 string3
```

And it will match any module that has all the strings listed.  This following command led me to anybase:

```
npm search binary convert
```

I hope this helps.